# Junit Mock responses are not returned in case of loop

Tags: spring-boot, junit4

I have some problem with Junit testcases , below is the case :
I have below method loop inside the void method :

```
List<Message> msgList = service1.getList();
for (Message message : msgList) {
 StorageObject object = cloudStorage.readObject(anotherObject);
 InputStream inputStream = object .getObjectContent();
 String text = IOUtils.toString(inputStream);
 // text to object mapping
 // third party service call
}
```

in my unit testcase, i have done below mocking :

1. service1.getList() to return the list of 2 message objects
2. mock storageobject and provided it some mock values as below

   StorageObject stObject = new StorageObject();
   stObject.setObjectContent(new StorageObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream( "Hi, This is a dummy and it would be json format".getBytes()), null));
   Mockito.when(cloudStorage.readObject(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(stObject );

When i execute the testcase, for first iteration it works perfectly and method execution returns the correct result but for second iteration inputStream doesn't have the valid values so text it returned as null, why so? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you mock the cloudStorage.readObject(); function if not then please try so as to return the mocked response everytime the function in called

Comment: Yes, already mocked, but not working. (Added line of code above)

Comment: @TarunGupta, are you sure that your test case requires usage of InputStreams, as anyway you are mocking all methods which use it?
Why don't perform mock text to object mapping and call third party service directly from the unit tests without using any streams?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your InputStream is being emptied after the first read.

You need to recreate it for each iteration.
You can [configure mockito](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.8.9/org/mockito/Mockito.html#answer_stubs) to return a newly created InputSteam mock object for each consequent call.

```
Mockito.when(cloudStorage.readObject(Mockito.any())).thenAnswer(new Answer() {
    Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
        StorageObject stObject = new StorageObject();
        stObject.setObjectContent(new StorageObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream("Hi, This is a dummy and it would be json format".getBytes()), null));
        return stObject;
    }
});
```

Comment: What is mock.someMethod in above code piece? is it cloudStorage.readObject right?

Comment: It is your mocked method. From your example it is
`cloudStorage.readS3Object(Mockito.any())).thenAnswer...`

Comment: Thanks alot VadymVL, its working fine with your solution

Comment: the above stub gives the constant mock response, I want to return the response based on the method argument, E.g.;

Comment: @TarunGupta, you can use `invocation` parameter in order to get arguments. Please see an example in the documentation - https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.8.9/org/mockito/Mockito.html#answer_stubs

Comment: Mockito.when(cloudStorage.readObject(Mockito.any())).thenAnswer(new Answer() { Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
 Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
String name = (String)args[0];
   if(name != null) {
          if("abc".equals(name)) {
            return new StorageObject(new StorageObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream("abc".getBytes()), null));
          } else if("xyz".equals(queue)) {
            return new StorageObject(new StorageObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream("xyz".getBytes()), null));
          }
        }
        return null;
    }
});

Comment: @TarunGupta, your code seems fine. Had you tried to debug it and see if it actually receives passed argumetns?

Comment: Thanks, its working fine now. Problem was with mock data.

Comment: @VadmVL, in the below stubbing I'm able to get the data Mockito.when(cloudStorage.readObject(Mockito.any())).thenAnswer(new Answer() { Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) { Object[] args = invocation.getArguments(); String name = (String)args[0];if("abc".equals(name)) { return new StorageObject(new ..........                            I have list of 2 records with queue name abc and xyz so when i execute the method i get data for both records. Now my use case is to invoke the same method in 5 parallel threads using conmpletable future and i want to return the mock data to 1 thread only